# collapsing accordion content in django for loop

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement for loop in my accordion. Everything seems to be fine except the fact that when I click on 3rd or 4th button then other bodies stay expanded. It should work exactly the same as in the first example [in Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/) so if you click on Accordion Item #2 then Accordion Item #1 and Accordion Item #3 collapse.

I am sure that the issue is with my `{% if forloop.first %}` but I am not sure how can I dynamically change that so it will collapse all accordion contents except active one.

My code:

```
  {% for category in top_categories %}
  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{{category.id}}">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#collapse{{category.id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{category.id}}">
          {{category.title}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapse{{category.id}}" class="accordion-collapse {% if forloop.first %} show {% else %} collapse {% endif %}" aria-labelledby="heading{{category.id}}"
        data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          {% for qa in category.qa.all|slice:"0:3" %}
              <a href="{{ qa.get_absolute_url }}">Q: {{qa}}</a><hr>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is that you are including <div class"accordion" id="accordionExample"> inside the loop. A secondary one is that the "collapse" class is also necessary for the first iteration. Try this:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  {% for category in top_categories %}
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading{{category.id}}">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse{{category.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse{{category.id}}">
          {{category.title}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapse{{category.id}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse {% if forloop.first %}show{% endif %}" aria-labelledby="heading{{category.id}}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          {% for qa in category.qa.all|slice:"0:3" %}
            <a href="{{ qa.get_absolute_url }}">Q: {{qa}}</a><hr>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```