# accordion collapse using for each loop

Tags: c#, css, accordion

I'm having some trouble with accordion collapsion.

I'm building a network monitor and every accordion is dynamically  added via foreach loops.
So i have accordions in accordions and foreach loops in for each loops

-> every parent accordion is the host machine
-> every child accordion in that parent accordion is each network adapter which holds the information inside.

The problem i'm facing is that due to the id and data-toggle arguments when I click on 1 accordion they all collapse, So I have changed the id for the child which controls the child and parent seperatly however every child is still the same meaning that every child collapses together and when it is collapsed when I click again it collapses the parent.

The problem probably persist in both th accordion logics as I only have teste with one host.

Question : How to fix this so every accordion host and adapter or parent and child can collapse seperatly?
main code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="accordion" id="accordionNetwork">
                @foreach(var item in hosts)
                {                    
                    <div class="accordion-item">
                        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                            <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                @item.Name - @item.IPv4 - @item.FQDN
                            </button>
                        </h2>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionNetwork">
                            <div class="accordion-body">                             
                             @foreach(var adapter in item.Adapters)
                             {
                                 <div class="accordion-item">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            @adapter.Name
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>

                                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionNetwork">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">                             
                                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                     
                             }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                    
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

child code is the inner foreach loops so:

```
@foreach(var adapter in item.Adapters)                             

{
                                 <div class="accordion-item">
                                    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                                        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                            @adapter.Name
                                        </button>
                                    </h2>

                                    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionNetwork">
                                        <div class="accordion-body">                             
                                                          
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                     
                             }
```

Comment: I believe this question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71207435/collapsing-accordion-content-in-django-for-loop
(It may not be a perfect answer since it does not apply to c# but the gist is the same - you need to create the html elements dynamically for each accordion component so they are not all controlled with the same id.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already fingured out how to do it.